# typescript configure to get helmet import working

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, helmet.js

so i'm just getting into typescript and i've ran into my first few stumbles.
so i use this line to import helmet in my project:

```
import * as helmet from "helmet";
```

but i keep running into this error

```
src/index.ts:3:25 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'helmet'. 'D:/Dev/ticktack/node_modules/helmet/index.cjs' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/helmet` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'helmet';`
```

and no, installing `@types/helmet` won't work since that package is just an empty stub.
MY first solution i came up with was to use `// @ts-ignore` before the import line wish "fixed" it. But it irked i went to look into the helmet module and they do indeed provide *.d.cts* and *.d.mts* files but ts-node doesn't recognize them, in fact just changing one from **index.d.cts** to **index.d.ts** truly fixed it.

now i suspect this is a problem in my tsconfig so can anyone please help me?!

here's my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "src/types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

**Edit:** this project was scaffolded using typeORM init with express, [here's a sapmle of my setup](https://gist.github.com/Alzanari/bcfada71f7f8c50c710ebb413fa04bef). this might shed some light on the reason why i'm having this issues

Comment: What do you mean by "package is just an empty stub"?

Comment: Make sure that you have installed the 'helmet' package correctly.

Comment: @LinDu it's literally what the package readme say, stub is used as "stand for something else". the usual types packages have an index.d.ts but the one helmet has been removed since the helmet package provide it's own type definitions.

Comment: @gretal i don't how i could've botched an install but i removed the package and try both npm and yarn. still nothing

Comment: It's weird that TS doesn't see the `.d.cts` file. When fetching types for dependencies it is supposed to look at the `"types"` field in helmet's `package.json`, which specifies that types live in `index.d.cts`, so it is supposed to pick them up. `index.d.ts` is the default file TS will look for if `"types"` field is not present. Can you check whether helmet's `package.json` in your setup has the `"types"` field? And what commands do you use to compile your project, simply `tsc`?

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. Sorry you're running into this. I made [a sample app to try to reproduce your problem](https://gist.github.com/EvanHahn/91fb6281f70d79761bda28d1f9ed1a40) but everything worked for me. Are you running the latest version of Helmet, TypeScript, and ts-node?

(Also, I _think_ you did this, but you don't need `@types/helmet` anymore because those are built into Helmet now.)

Comment: @EvanHahn hum, then my next guess would be some weirdness in my own setup, FYI, the project was scaffolded using typeORM init with express. [here's a sample of my files](https://gist.github.com/Alzanari/bcfada71f7f8c50c710ebb413fa04bef). and apologies in advanced if i'm just sending you on a wild goose chase

Comment: @AlexChashin indeed it specifies types in package.json, next part of the puzzle might be related to how the project was created, check my comment to Evan

Comment: @AlZanari It looks like you're using an old version of TypeScript. What happens if you upgrade to the latest with `npm install typescript@latest --save-dev`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're using an incompatible/old version of TypeScript (`4.5.2`) with your version of Helmet (`7.0.0`).

Update TypeScript to the latest version (`5.1.6` as of writing this) to resolve the issue:

`npm i -D typescript@latest` or

`pnpm add -D typescript@latest` or

`yarn add -D typescript@latest`

Depending on your package manager of choice. :)

Source: `"typescript": "^5.1.6"` as a dev dependency in the Helmet repo (as of writing this) https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/blob/main/package.json